# 'ddlItem' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm getting this error whenever I try to bind data inside gridview dropdownlist.

Here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Description"  SortExpression="ddlItem">
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px" SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ddlItem") %>'>
         </asp:DropDownList>
       </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Here is the code behind (c#):

```
        private void SetInitialRowToGrid()
            {
                // Initialize and Set initial row of Datatable
                var tempDataTable = new DataTable();
                tempDataTable.Columns.Add("lblId");
                tempDataTable.Columns.Add("ddlItem");
                tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtUnit");
                tempDataTable.Columns.Add("txtQty");
                tempDataTable.Rows.Add("1", "", "", "");

                // Store that datatable into viewstate
                ViewState["TempTable"] = tempDataTable;

                // Attach Gridview Datasource to datatable        
                gvItemList.DataSource = tempDataTable;
                gvItemList.DataBind(); //Here I'm getting the error.
            }

    protected void gvItemList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                DropDownList ddlItem = (e.Row.FindControl("ddlItem") as DropDownList);
                Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_ItemTableAdapter item;
                item = new Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_ItemTableAdapter();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                dt = item.GetItems();

                ddlItem.DataSource = dt;
                ddlItem.DataTextField = "Item";
                ddlItem.DataValueField = "Item";
                ddlItem.DataBind();
                ddlItem.Items.Insert(0, new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem("--Select an Item--", "0"));
            }
        }

protected void ddlSiteID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter ds;
        ds = new Jilu1TableAdapters.tbl_Jr_BOMTableAdapter();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = ds.GetVersion(ddlSiteID.SelectedValue);

        ddlVersion.DataSource = dt;
        ddlVersion.DataValueField = "Version";
        ddlVersion.DataTextField = "Version";
        ddlVersion.DataBind();

        int ver = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVersion.Text);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();

        dt1 = ds.GetDetails(ddlSiteID.SelectedValue, ver);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
        {
            txtSiteName.Text = (row["txtSiteName"].ToString());
            ddlSiteType.Text = (row["ddlSiteType"].ToString());
            txtNoBTS.Text = (row["txtNoBTS"].ToString());
            txtNoLinks.Text = (row["txtNoLinks"].ToString());
            txtLoadBand.Text = (row["txtLoadBand"].ToString());
            ddlEBAvailability.Text = (row["ddlEBAvailability"].ToString());
            txtEBPhase.Text = (row["txtEBPhase"].ToString());
            txtDGCapacity.Text = (row["txtDGCapacity"].ToString());
            txtDGPhase.Text = (row["txtDGPhase"].ToString());            
        }
        gvItemList.DataSource = dt1;
        gvItemList.DataBind();
    }
```

I tried putting `Text = 'Bind("ddlItem")', Datasourse, SelectedValue` but still no luck.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your datasource is string then fine else you need to set the DataTextField and DataValueField (Properties of object which you are binding). And check whether binding code is in Page_Load postback or !IIPostBack

Comment: data which bind on dropdownlist is a string.

Comment: Learn how to ask a question, when you have a problem-> explanation like I had no luck is not accurate. Debug your problem and see what happen.

Comment: @mybirthname I meant to say, I was still getting the same error. As I've mention above.

Answer (score 0):

In this code ,

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlItem" runat="server" Height="25px" Width="200px"  
 SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ddlItem") %>'>
 </asp:DropDownList>
```

you set `SelectedValue` to `'<%# Eval("ddlItem") %>'` but `ddlItem` is not exist in your datasource fields .

Put the correct field which you want to display in your dropdownlist .
And I suggest you to set `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` of your DropDownList .
Set it like `DataTextField="ddlItem" DataValueField="ddlItem"` .
Hope it's help for you :)

Comment: Actually 1st I'm trying to set an initial row, when the page loads. After that when user enter an id, data from database will populate on gridview. That is the whole idea about this.

Comment: What's happen when you add `DataTextField="ddlItem" DataValueField="ddlItem"` ?

Comment: thank you for replying. I tried the way you suggested, But still having the same error. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your way is wrong

try this below way

```
protected void gvItemList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
      {
            if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
            {
              DropDownList ddList= (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlItem");
              //bind dropdownlist
              DataTable dt = con.GetData("select * from tablename");//selected data from db or  anywhere for bind ddl
              ddList.DataSource = dt;
              ddList.DataTextField = "YourCOLName";//id
              ddList.DataValueField = "YourCOLName";//displaying name
              ddList.DataBind();

              DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;                 
              ddList.SelectedValue = dr["YourCOLName"].ToString();// default selected value
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: why you need `SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ddlItem") %>'` in your dropdown?

Comment: please remove the `SelectedValue='<%# Eval("ddlItem") %>'` in your dropdown, then your code should work ya

Comment: See, the whole idea of this grid is, at first when the page load happens there will be a single blank row in the grid view which is "SetInitialRowToGrid()". When user select an id there will be a postback happening, at that time data from database need to populate on the gridview. Hope you understand now.